# How to solve this DE involving a convolution $\int_0^t ds \ e^{-\kappa s} \cos(\omega s) f(t-s)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, laplace-transform, convolution

I've got a DE of the form
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = A - B f(t) - C \int_0^t ds\ e^{-\kappa s} \cos(\omega s) f(t-s)
$$
which I want to solve given an initial condition $f(0^{+})=f_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. All the constants are **positive** $A, B, C, \kappa, \omega > 0$.

Is there a way to solve this?

It seems that the solution should be falling off exponentially, but inserting an anstaz of the from $e^{-\alpha t}$ gives me non-sense.

I have tried the Laplace transform $F(q) \equiv \mathcal{L}\{ f \}(q) = \int_0^\infty dt f(t) e^{-qt}$ where the convolution splits up nicely, and the above DE gets mapped to
$$
q F(q) - f_0 = A - B F(q) - C F(q) \frac{q+\kappa}{(q+\kappa)^2 + \omega^2 }
$$
Solving for $F(q)$ gives
$$
F(q) \ = \ \frac{f_0 + A}{q + B + C \frac{q+\kappa}{(q+\kappa)^2 + \omega^2 }}
$$
I am unable to perform the inverse Laplace transform on this rational polynomial (I can't find a general way to do a partial fraction decomposition here).

Is there a different method (other than Laplace) for solving such DEs?

EDIT: I've started a bounty, as I am unable to deal with the partial fraction decomposition. I would really like to determine the large $t\to \infty$ behvaiour for this function, where I think it is exponentially damped like $e^{-Ct}$ and falling to some constant. I have tried (to no avail) looking at the inverse Laplace transform
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} dq\ \frac{f_0 + A}{q + B + C \frac{q+\kappa}{(q+\kappa)^2 + \omega^2 }} e^{tq}
$$
where $\gamma$ is larger than the real parts of the singularities of $\frac{f_0 + A}{q + B + C \frac{q+\kappa}{(q+\kappa)^2 + \omega^2 }}$.

Comment: The denominator of $F$ (when simplified) is a cubic which is guaranteed to have at least one real root, so a partial fraction decomposition (and inverse transform) is possible. Although you might have to use numerical methods to find the roots.

Comment: You should be able to do the partial fraction decomposition. Expand the denominator and find its roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach using system of linear equations. Let us consider
$$
g(t) = C\int_0^t e^{-\kappa s}\cos(\omega s)f(t-s)\mathrm ds = C\int_0^t e^{-\kappa (t-s)}\cos(\omega (t-s))f(s)\mathrm ds,
$$
$$
h(t) = C\int_0^t e^{-\kappa s}\sin(\omega s)f(t-s)\mathrm ds = C\int_0^t e^{-\kappa (t-s)}\sin(\omega (t-s))f(s)\mathrm ds.
$$ Then we can find that
$$
g'(t) = Cf(t) -\kappa g(t)-\omega h(t),
$$
$$
h'(t) = -\kappa h(t)+\omega g(t),
$$ which implies that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\begin{array}{c}f\\g\\h\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}-B&-C&0\\C&-\kappa&-\omega\\0&\omega&-\kappa\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}f\\g\\h\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}A\\0\\0\end{array}\right],
$$ or equivalently, the equation of the form
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{x}(t)=M\textbf{x}(t)+ \textbf{b},
$$with initial condition
$$
\textbf{x}(0)=\textbf{v}=\left[\begin{array}{c}f_0\\0\\0\end{array}\right].
$$ Since we are assuming $B(\kappa^2+\omega^2) +C^2\kappa> 0$, $M$ is invertible. It follows that the solution is given by
$$
\textbf{x}(t)=e^{tM}\left(\textbf{v}+M^{-1}\textbf{b}\right) -M^{-1}\textbf{b}.
$$
Though this does not provide a closed form solution of $f$, it could be computed numerically by evaluating $e^{tM}$.